# Environmental Variables on AWS EC2 using Elasticbeanstalk

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I configured a postgressql database on ec2 instance. Now I want to talk to this database server using a different ec2 instance which is running a python/django framework.

My settings.py file contains:

```
DATABASES = {
   'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
    'NAME': os.environ['DB_NAME'],
    'USER': os.environ['DB_USERNAME'],
    'PASSWORD': os.environ['DB_PASSWORD'],
    'HOST': os.environ['DB_HOSTNAME'],
    'PORT': os.environ['DB_PORT'],
   }
}
```

Where "DB_NAME" and other variables are defined in .ebextensions/*.config file under option_settings. When I push the code to AWS, the deployment log files shows that DB_NAME does not exists. I am not sure where I am going wrong. The Elasticbeanstalk console shows the variables though.

Comment: Can you share the `.ebextensions/*.config` without giving away your secrets? It would clarify the issue to see how you declared those variables.